# A compact family of holomorphic functions and their corresponding compact ranges?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cv.complex-variables

Let $C = [0,1]^n \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be the closed unit cube. For some open set $V \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ such that $C \subset V$, denote by $\mathcal{F}$ some compact family of holomorphic functions from $V$ to $\mathbb{C}^n$ such that $\Phi(C) \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ for each $\Phi \in \mathcal{F}$. Denote by $\mathcal{K} = \{ \Phi(C) \; : \; \Phi \in \mathcal{F} \}$.

**Question.** How large can one make $\mathcal{K}$, under the condition that $\mathcal{F}$ is compact?

**Motivation.** In the Hausdorff metric, the family $\mathcal{J}$ of compact subsets of the closed unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is compact. It is perhaps too much to ask that $\mathcal{K} = \mathcal{J}$, but another interesting family would be $\mathcal{C}$, the family of closed convex subsets of the closed unit ball. This family is also maybe a bit too much to ask, since the boundary of a convex set can have some bad points.

**A trivial example.**
By taking $\mathcal{F}$ to be a set of affine maps, one can generate the family $\mathcal{K}$ of parallelepipeds in the closed unit ball, including degenerate ones. It is also not too hard to generate all simplices in the closed unit ball.

**Discussion.**
What's happening is that this is quite far outside of what I usually do and I can see from the literature that there's all kinds of things I know nothing about, in algebraic geometry for example. It also vaguely seems to me that one may have a little flexibility on the choice of topology on $\mathcal{F}$. At present, I've got functions $\Phi_p \in \mathcal{F}$ parametrized by a compact metric space $p \in P$ (e.g. a compact metric space of affine maps) and I need the map $p \to \Phi_p(z)$ to be uniformly Lipschitz: $\|\Phi_p(z) - \Phi_q(z)\| \leq Ld(p,q)$ for all $z \in V$ and $p,q \in P$.

Is this a well-known problem?